# ASP .NET Correlation Failed Error Google OAuth2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, google-oauth

i am developing an ASP .NET 6 Core MVC project.i added google authentication.
but when i try to authorize using Google as external login,it shows Correlation Failed error.
this is my program.cs file where i add identity options and authorization:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    })
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = builder.Configuration["App:FacebookClientId"];
        facebookOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["App:FacebookClientSecret"];
    });
```

and this is the error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Correlation failed.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

i can not figure out that did i miss something.i watched tutorial and did the same tasks which were shown in video.

THIS IS THE FULL STACK TRACE

```
Exception: Correlation failed.
```

Show raw exception details
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace please?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary i added them into post

Comment: Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: no i am using http. "htttp://localhost"

Comment: You're welcome, enjoy coding :)